Is it valid to use an "infinite" number of universal/existential instantiations in a proof?
I was thinking about the statement that the sequential definition of a limit of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and the "epsilon-delta" definition are equivalent. Specifically, I am interested in the direction "sequence implies epsilon". (Please note the question is not about the specifics of this proof, I am just trying to provide some context!)
Suppose for any (real) sequence $(a_n)$ that convereges to $c$, the sequence $(f(a_n))$ converges to $L$, where $c,L \in \mathbb{R}$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose that it is not true that $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x)= L$. I.e., we assume $$\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta>0 \exists x \in \mathbb{R} \bigg(0 < \mid x-c \mid < \delta \text{ } \land \text{ } \mid f(x)-L\mid \geq \epsilon\bigg )$$
By existential instantiation, we may write $$\forall \delta>0 \exists x \in \mathbb{R} \bigg(0 < \mid x-c \mid < \delta \text{ }\land \text{ } \mid f(x)-L\mid \geq \epsilon_0\bigg )$$
for some $\epsilon_0 > 0$.
The next part of the 'proof' is the crux of my question. I wanted to consider a sequence which I define as follows. First, consider the sequence $\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)$. For the k-the term of this sequence, by universal instantiation I have $$\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \bigg(0 < \mid x-c \mid < \frac{1}{k} \text{ } \land \text{ } \mid f(x)-L\mid \geq \epsilon_0\bigg)$$
Correspondingly, I may use existential instantiation and write (for any given k-th term)
$$0 < \mid x_k-c \mid < \frac{1}{k} \text{ and }\mid f(x)-L\mid \geq \epsilon_0$$
My idea was to use this to define a sequence $(x_k)$ where we would have the property that $\forall k \big(0 < \mid x_k-c \mid < \frac{1}{k}\big)$.

Is this a valid construction of the sequence $(x_k)$?
My knowledge of logic is very limited, but I am concerned that this approach of "infinite" instantiations is not valid. Specifically, it feels like I am trying to use an "inductive step", because for any formal/finite proof, I obviously could not explicitly construct this sequence. We get around this when proving statements about the natural number of the form $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} P(n)$ by having induction as an axiom or rule of inference.
However, for instantiations in first order logic, is there such an axiom or rule of inference that allows us to use them an infinite amount of times in a proof?
More generally, my question can be summarised as follows:
Given a statement of the form $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y \in \mathbb{R} \big(P(x,y)\big)$ and a real sequence $(a_n)$, can I use universal and existential instantiations to construct a sequence $(b_n)$ whereby we have $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \big( P(a_n,b_n) \big)$?

See also this question on MathOverflow – Andreas Blass's answer seems to address much of what you are asking.

Please do not use the comments to answer questions.  If you have an answer, use the "Your Answer" box at the bottom of the page to write and post an answer.

For natural deduction, a proof is a finite recursively defined tree of rules I think

What you've found is the problem of the axiom of choice (specifically, the countable version). In its full generality, this axiom says that given any family of nonempty sets, you are allowed to pick a single element from each one.
In this case, the sets are $S_n := \{y \in \mathbb{R} : P(a_n,y)\}$ which are guaranteed to be nonempty by the hypothesis on $P$. And then we pick a sequence $(b_n)$ such that $b_n \in S_n$ for all $n$ by the axiom of choice.
Many key results in mathematics require various forms of choice to prove.
However, some logicians think that this axiom is not very good, because it can produce many results like the Banach-Tarski Paradox and the existence of well-orderings for arbitrary sets, which seem crazy to our intuition.
So you might be a fan of Constructive Logic, in which you're only allowed to make finite choices.

Thank you! How do we "know" every one of the sets is non-empty in order to apply the AoC? My thinking is to show every set is non-empty requires us to use existential instantiation, but then we are back to the initial problem! Any idea where I'm going wrong with the logic?

@masiewpao: You can prove that by contradiction. Suppose $S_k$ is empty for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then apply the hypothesis on P to immediately reach a contradiction. When we reject the assumption, we're left with the conclusion that $\neg \exists k \in \mathbb{N} : S_k = \emptyset$, which simplifies to $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} : S_k \neq \emptyset$.

Thank you! and thank you @Kevin for the very helpful comment!

You are simply using the axiom of choice.
Your existential instantiation argument proves the following statement: for each $k$ there exists a nonempty set $X_k$ of values for $x$ satisfying the inequalities $0 < |x-c| < \frac{1}{k}$ and $|f(x)-L| \ge \epsilon_0$. You are then applying the axiom of choice to simultaneously pick a value $x_k \in X_k$ for each $k$ and to make a sequence $(x_k)$ out of those picks.

Thank you! What I'm not sure about is how we can know that each $X_k$ is non-empty without first using instantiation? So to build out our family of non-empty sets we must use infinite instantiation and then we can use the AoC to give us a choice function. This feels circular and I'm wondering if there is another axiom/rule of inference that lets use deduce all of the $X_k$ are non-empty?

@masiewpao, I believe that as I used to (and still catch myself do), you may be envisioning the non-emptiness of all the $X_k$ as being shown individually -- perhaps "in parallel" so that in some sense the max cost is incurred rather than the sum (which, had $k$ ranged over an uncountable domain, would have cropped up still further philosophical nightmares) and the proof is thus able to proceed through that step. While for many informal purposes this works, as evidenced by how long I had avoided the majority who apparently never thought anything like this metaphor, ...

...legally your proof isn't showing $X_1\neq\empty,X_2\neq\empty,$ this $X_k\neq\empty,$ that other $X_k\neq\empty$ so much as that an arbitrary $X_k$ is non-empty -- operative word being "an" as opposed to "many" -- and this is an instance where the technical distinction rears its head and clearly becomes relevant. It's jarring, akin to my mistrust of the notion of a variable as "a quantity that varies" whereas the definite conglomeration of values it's eligible to assume feels comparatively solid, but ironically the naive-sounding "a single $X_k$ that [could] vary" proves more accurate here.

TL;DR -- "(for each $k$, your existential instantiation argument produces) $X_k \neq \emptyset$ ..." might be better read "your existential instantiation argument produces that (for each $k$, we have $X_k \neq \emptyset$ ...)"; said argument is being run just once, nebulous/anonymous as the arbitrary $k$ may be.

Nice rewording @Vandermonde.

Others have already correctly mentioned the axiom of choice. Let me describe its use through a slightly different view point, the one of choice functions.
Let $P(a,b)$ be any predicate.
Consider the following two statements, which are not equivalent, in general.
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\forall a\in A. \exists b\in B. \ P(a,b)
\\
\nLeftrightarrow
\\
\exists b\in B. \forall a\in A. \ P(a,b)
\end{array}
$$
Indeed, swapping the order of quantifiers like that is not sound, in general. (The classic counterexample: for each natural $a$ there is a larger one $b$, but there is no natural $b$ which is greater than all $a$.)
However, the axiom of choice allows us to perform a similar quantifier exchange, turning $b$ into a choice function. We then obtain an always valid equivalence:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\forall a\in A. \exists b\in B. \ P(a,b)
\\
\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad
\\
\exists b: \color{red}{A\to B}. \forall a\in A. \ P(a,\color{red}{b(a)})
\end{array}
$$
The intuition is that $b(a)$ chooses, once and for all, one the the elements of $B$ that is related to $a$ by the predicate $P$. The above equivalence, involving the existence of such a choice function $b(-)$, is (one of the possible forms of) the axiom of choice.
In your own case, your statement is of the form
$$\forall \delta>0 . \exists x \in \mathbb R . P(\delta,x)$$
You can use that to prove
$$\forall k\in\mathbb N^+ . \exists x \in \mathbb R . P(1/k,x)$$
Then, apply choice to get
$$\exists x : \mathbb N^+ \to \mathbb R . \forall k\in\mathbb N^+ .  P(1/k,x(k))$$
which is what you wanted.
